# Use class method while creating new instance

Tags: c#, oop

My class:

```
public class AvailabilityDataWithoutAging
{
    public string BranchPlant { get; set; }
    public string Location { get; set; }
    public string ItemCode { get; set; }
    public string ItemDescription { get; set; }
    public int PiecesPerPalletMaster { get; set; }
    public int NumberOfLots { get; set; }
    public int NumberOfPalletsConversion { get; set; }
    public int AvailablePrimary { get; set; }
    public int TempPrimary { get; set; }
    public int BlankPrimary { get; set; }
    public int HoldAutomaticPrimary { get; set; }
    public int HoldSpecificPrimary { get; set; }

    public void CalculatePrimaryFromConversion()
    {
        NumberOfPalletsConversion = AvailablePrimary/PiecesPerPalletMaster;
    }
}
```

I want to use method `CalculatePrimaryFromConversion` within this:

```
retValue = _data
    .GroupBy(av => new {av.limcu, av.lilocn, av.imlitm})
    .Select(av => new AvailabilityDataWithoutAging
    {
        BranchPlant = av.Key.limcu,
        Location = av.Key.lilocn,
        ItemCode = av.Key.imlitm,
        ItemDescription = av.Max(s => s.imdsc),
        PiecesPerPalletMaster = Convert.ToInt32(_JDE8dal.GetF41002Conversion(av.Max(s=>s.liitm),"PL","EA")),
        AvailablePrimary = av.Sum(s => s.lipqoh),
        NumberOfLots = av.Count(s => s.lilotn.StartsWith("1")),
        TempPrimary = av.Sum(s => s.lilotn=="TEMP" ? s.lipqoh : 0),
        BlankPrimary = av.Sum(s => s.lilotn == "" ? s.lipqoh : 0),
        HoldAutomaticPrimary = 0,
        HoldSpecificPrimary = 0
    }).ToList();
```

Is there a way to do it?

**ADDITIONAL INFO:**

I do not want to do it only within select, this was an example. I want to be able to do it on the fly while i instantiate the class. Sorry for the confusion

Comment: What about creating & using a read-only property, such as `NumberOfPalletsConversion`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't do that within the Select expression. You need to loop over the resulting list and call CalculaePrimaryFromConversion on each item.

However I would recommend another approach.

Make NumberOfPalletsConversion a calculated property

```
public class AvailabilityDataWithoutAging
{
    public string BranchPlant { get; set; }
    public string Location { get; set; }
    public string ItemCode { get; set; }
    public string ItemDescription { get; set; }
    public int PiecesPerPalletMaster { get; set; }
    public int NumberOfLots { get; set; }
    public int NumberOfPalletsConversion
    {
      get
      {
          return AvailablePrimary/PiecesPerPalletMaster;
      }
    }
    public int AvailablePrimary { get; set; }
    public int TempPrimary { get; set; }
    public int BlankPrimary { get; set; }
    public int HoldAutomaticPrimary { get; set; }
    public int HoldSpecificPrimary { get; set; }
}
```

Another alternative is to create a public constructor when you enter all arguments except NumberOfPalletsConversion and do the calculation inside the constructor.

Answer (score 1):

```
.Select(av => 
{ 
    var r = new AvailabilityDataWithoutAging
    {
        BranchPlant = av.Key.limcu,
        Location = av.Key.lilocn,
        ItemCode = av.Key.imlitm,
        ItemDescription = av.Max(s => s.imdsc),
        PiecesPerPalletMaster = Convert.ToInt32(_JDE8dal.GetF41002Conversion(av.Max(s=>s.liitm),"PL","EA")),
        AvailablePrimary = av.Sum(s => s.lipqoh),
        NumberOfLots = av.Count(s => s.lilotn.StartsWith("1")),
        TempPrimary = av.Sum(s => s.lilotn=="TEMP" ? s.lipqoh : 0),
        BlankPrimary = av.Sum(s => s.lilotn == "" ? s.lipqoh : 0),
        HoldAutomaticPrimary = 0,
        HoldSpecificPrimary = 0
    };
    r.CalculatePrimaryFromConversion();
    return r;
})
```

Comment: While this is a viable alternative to OP's method, does it really answer the question? I think OP wants to call the method within the initialization.

Comment: @DavidFrye Why not? He asked how to use the method within a `Select` operation. And this is how to do it.

Comment: Added additional info. Sorry for confusion